# USB-C to HDMI Adapter disconnects/reconnects when gnome-control-center starts

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-control-center, usb-c

```
Lenovo Thinkpad T15
Intel Core i7-10510U @ 1.80GHz × 8 
Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
16GB RAM

Ubuntu 20.04 (minimal install w/3rd party drivers)
GNOME 3.36.3
X11
```

I have a USB-C 7-in-1 adapter with an HDMI port that works fine most of the time, however the monitor disconnects/reconnects whenever I open the Gnome Settings menu.  I messed around a bit and noticed this happens any time `gnome-control-center` is run regardless of args so even the following commands cause it to happen even though the window isn't launched:

`gnome-control-center --version`
`gnome-control-center --help`

I have 2 USB-C ports with DisplayPort capability and this happens with both of them.  I also have a single USB-C to HDMI adapter and this issue does not happen while using that on either of these ports.  For the the 7-in-1, it doesn't matter if any other ports on the adapter are used, the issue happens even if HDMI is the only thing plugged in.

7-in-1 Adapter: https://qgeemtech.com/collections/best-seller/products/usb-c-hub-hdmi-adapter-qgeem-7-in-1
USB-C/HDMI Adapter: https://qgeemtech.com/collections/best-seller/products/qgeem-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter-4k-cable

In addition I've been noticing random issues with gnome on this setup where it will get into a state where it's hogging cpu resources to the point the GUI slows down (~1s or more to respond to cursor moves). When it gets like this restarting gnome-shell solves the problem.  Not sure if this is related at all, I'm back to using Linux after a 4-5 year break so not sure what kind of experiences/bugs are common right now.

Comment: I have the same issues with 3-in-1 Adapter: https://gembird.com/item.aspx?id=11205 . The monitor which is on this adapter recognizes the connection around 10 seconds later to the one which is plugged directly via hdmi. Also the connection is lost for the moment when I enter Display configuration in Gnome Control Center. As for the mouse issue symptoms I noticed them as well few times but I thought that my battery was dying or interference since I used the wireless mouse. The issue was not frequent.

Have you solved your issues by any chance?

Comment: I never figured out the source of the cursor issue but it went away after doing a clean OS install.  The external monitor/gnome still happens with gnome but I stopped using gnome for the most part so haven't spent anymore time trying to solve it.